# How come systemctl status postgresql.service and systemctl status postgresql@10-main show different results?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Not sure I really understand what's going on.

Originally, I'm trying to connect to a remote host (which I can ping, access via SSH) but cannot connect through psql

```
Error: psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host <HOST> and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

After checking a couple of things, I stumbled upon different results from `postgresql.service` and `postgresql@10-main` :

**postgresql.service -- active (exited)**

```
  ~ sudo systemctl status postgresql.service
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled;  
vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Don 2018-01-04 15:24:14 CET; 2min 29s ago
  Process: 10954 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10954 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

**postgresql@10-main -- active (running)**

```
  ~ systemctl status postgresql@10-main             
● postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Don 2018-01-04 15:24:14 CET; 5min ago
  Process: 10920 ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast %i stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
  Process: 10929 ExecStart=postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10936 (postgres)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@10-main.service
           ├─10936 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/1
           ├─10938 postgres: 10/main: checkpointer process                                                            
           ├─10939 postgres: 10/main: writer process                                                                  
           ├─10940 postgres: 10/main: wal writer process                                                              
           ├─10941 postgres: 10/main: autovacuum launcher process                                                     
           ├─10942 postgres: 10/main: stats collector process                                                         
           └─10943 postgres: 10/main: bgworker: logical replication launcher                                          

Jan 04 15:24:12 floppy systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...
Jan 04 15:24:14 floppy systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
```

- Is this related to my problem with connecting to the remote host ?
- Why are two different services running (showing different results) ?

**PS: I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04**

Thanks a lot

Comment: _Connection refused_ happens probably because postgresql is not listening to remote connections, which is the default security. Configure it through the **listen_addresses** parameter. The rest looks normal, it's just the _systemd_ output that is hard to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have multiple postgres clusters running on the same machine. The main thing you need to check is the postgres port number, which you want to connect to.

Check if postgres instance on your port is running or not. Then check the server details from where you want to connect via ssh is listed in your `pg_hba.conf` file. If these are done, you should be able to connect to the remote postgres cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I posted as a guest so I cannot edit to provide more details. The port is 5432 and is open and accessible (`netstat` shows the correct output). Firewall is disabled, `postgres.conf` has what it needs (`listen_addresses`, `port`) and I allowed everything in `pg_hba`. Also, I don't own the server so I cannot really check things on that side, but it's supposed to work (other people can connect) :(.

Comment: Can you provide the psql command being used to connect. It coud be that the command is wrong, if others are able to connect. Mainly the setting in `pg_hba` file has to be checked on the remote server you want to access. So you will have to get them checked somehow.

Comment: `psql -U <username> -d <dbname> -h <host> -p 5432` I think it's correct as I've used it in the past. But i'm still not quite understanding why I have these two services that run. I've purged postgres and freshly reinstalled via `apt-get` and still i can't connect. I previously had two version in parallel (9.6 and 10), maybe that's for something.

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu and Debian

If you're using Ubuntu, rather than using systemd's `systemctl` to gauge the status of your clusters use the distro's own `pg_lsclusters`. It'll tell you if they're running and the port number,

```
$ pg_lsclusters 
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when I changed the  `pg_hba.conf` file.I am using Linux VM in order to change the `pg_hba.conf` file I had to change the `/car/lib/pgsql/15/data` permission but after the changes, I forgot to give the correct permission to this folder.

```
sudo chmod 0700 data
```